# Eclipse not loading WAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, war

I received some java code and a WAR file for a web application that I need to test.

My overall goal is to be able to test the web application functionality and potentially make modifications to the code if need be.

I seem to be stuck on correctly loading this into eclipse.

I grabbed the WAR file and did a Import where I attempted to import the WAR file into a (Web -> WAR) project. The first issue was Eclipse was complaining there not being enough memory or the heap size. So I changed the java memory options in the eclipse.ini file. This seemed to resolve the complaining about the memory.

I restarted eclipse and attempted to import the Web - War again now it goes through the process of pretending like it is importing the war file but nothing happens after it finishes.

So overall my questions are 
1 What is the correct process to load the war and source code into eclipse 
2. Why is Eclipse not loading the war file

Comment: A .war runs on a server, the source code should be loaded into eclipse.  These are 2 different concepts.  Eclipse can build the war and you can run that compiled .war through eclipse, but to the best of my knowledge, eclipse itself cannot load/run a .war file

Comment: You are doing it well. To import a war file, you must execute File > Import > WAR file and chose the file and project. I suggest you fill in a **new** project. Click Finish. Then, what happens? Has been created the new project?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test a WAR file, you must deploy it to a Servlet container.  Common Servlet containers include: Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss (which actually uses Tomcat), WebSphere, and WebLogic.

JBoss, WebSphere, and WebLogic are JEE environments, but they each have a Servlet container.

Answer (score 0):

WAR file generally contains compiled version of .Java file i.e. .class file and other web related stuff.

You unzip the .war file with WinZip or similar software, if it contains source code attached, then only you can view or modify the code.ELSE you can do the below steps to run the application.

Install a server e.g Apache Tomcat to your PC.
Start the server from CMD.
Open the server home page.
Deploy your WAR file. Now you will be able to see the Application running.

If you want  to modify the code then you should have .Java files inside your war file.